# Download patch from Review board

Tags: review-board

How would one download a review board patch from command line. Lets say a review has multiple versions of patch uploaded ( after multiple reviews), i want a way to download the latest patch ( and eventually build, test and commit on behalf of developer). i was directly getting the patch from a python script by retrieving http://urlforcodereview.example.com/r/4/diff/raw/ but this no longer works with our new installation (1.7.25).

I also tried curl --user user:pass http://reviews.example.com/api/review-requests/8/diffs/1/ -A text/x-patch as given in the documentation, and i get the fields for the diff but not the exact diff ( patch).

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Dinesh G

Answer (score 1):

i don't know if that [link](https://www.reviewboard.org/docs/rbtools/dev/rbt/commands/patch/) from review board wiki may help

it is the patch command/

did you try it ?

Comment: i don't have the permission to comment on the original post, so i added that link as an answer and wishs it helps you.